# Regarding Michelson-Morley experiment

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, speed-of-light

The partially silvered glass plate splits the oncoming beam of light and the two resulting beams continue in mutually perpendicular directions, one above and the other along the velocity of apparatus, and then from these the two mirrors, they are reflected back to the plate.
My doubt is regarding the case for which the mirror is placed perpendicularly above.

Here,light travels not directly upwards after the splitting, but rather a longer, tilted path as the mirror above has moved from it's original place.
However, shouldn't light travel directly straight up and miss the mirror as the mirror has moved ahead?

Comment: I think you are confused about the experiment. None of the mirrors were above another. All of the mirrors were in a horizontal plane.

Comment: I meant the transverse mirror.

Answer (score 0):

The aether speed on earth being only ~0.1% of that of light, these considerations in practice have negligible effect.